# how do i come up with a rating algorithm/equation?

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, math, seo

I am trying to come up with a rating algorithm - so what it would do is, from the set of keywords a user has(for SEO), each keyword is provided a rating between 1-10 (10 being the best opportunity from that set) - the rating will be derived by comparing the 'search volume' the keyword has v/s the 'keyword difficulty' -  [here](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/302048/3fb0e3e135f881a258dd5e33cfed578b) is a screenshot of the rating column with dummy data as of now but will give you an idea ; so essentially what this would help the user do is figure out which keyword would be the best one to work on, from the set of all the keywords the user currently has

As an example of someone already doing something similar (rating algorithm from a set of choices) in another niche (flight search) is `momondo`, please do a random flight search on `momondo.com` and you'd see that it comes up with a [rating](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/302047/b9d6dd9b24227803c4d876d94493fca8) by comparing price and average flight time.

All above given, was wondering what would be the best equation I could work with to come up with the rating value i'm after

Hopefully i've not written the question in the confusing way, in case I have, do let me know and i'll expand :-)

Comment: Looks like a machine learning algo could do the job easily. Try linear regression

Answer (score 0):

If the only 2 factors you're considering are search volume (v) and keyword difficulty (d), then you should use a logarithmic scale and just have a simple equation such as:

```
KW Rating = (v * (10-d))/10
```

You could make that (11-d) if you don't want to assign a rating of 0 for extremely difficult keywords if they have ridiculously high volumes.